# repair drywall cornerbead (edger?)

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

I have this damaged drywall corner. I saw a couple of videos, some recommend to remove old loose mud over the cracked area and put on a new mud, wait till it dry, sand and put more if necessary, dry, sand etc. Other videos suggest to tape the area before putting a new mud.

My questions:

1. Is it important to tape it, or more a matter of taste?
2. Does the tape add extra force to hold the new mud?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plaster/joint compound has cracked along the line of the corner-bead below. Adding tape to your repair will strengthen the repair (reduce likelihood of re-cracking) but will also require you to remove paint and plaster to the width of the tape, all along the crack, or you will see a bulge. That said, I recommend doing it.

Comment: Is all the drywall tape of the same width? Also, what type of mud would you suggest for this repair? I don't mean brand name, but there's a lot in hardware store, which particular type should be appropriate. Thanks.